# Installing Netgear WNA1000 Wifi adapter driver without "netgear genie"

Tags: wireless-networking, drivers

I've installed the provided software with my WiFi adapter, but it includes the tool "Netgear Genie".

The problem is, I already have it, and now I have two copies of it running side-by-side! I want to remove the one provided with the driver, but they aren't separate in the Control Panel.

[image]

I'm on Windows 7. There are two folders in Program Files, one "netgear genie", and one "netgear", which contains the folder WNA1000 and the executable "wna1000.exe", which launches the mini-version (?) of netgear genie:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which OS are you using?

Are there two program folders for Genie? If so, see if there is an uninstaller in the folder for the one you wish to remove.

If it is Windows, [check using msconfig](http://www.netsquirrel.com/msconfig/index.html) to see if there are 2 startup entries for genie and untick one.

Comment: Did you look in msconfig?

Comment: Yes I was able to disable it, even if I couldn't uninstall it. Thanks.